# getting a path of .xslt file in rcp application

Tags: file, eclipse-plugin, path

In RCP application we kept the .xslt file under the resources folder. 
but the path of .xslt file not getting  in rcp application

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you include resource folder in build.properties and you can access the file by using  URI  `platform:/plugin/<plugin-name>/<folder-name>/test.xslt`